# Recent project on Visual Studio does not appear on right-click (Windows)

Tags: windows, taskbar

I reinstalled windows and visual studio recently, and I no longer have recent projects on a right click

[image]

I can't even pinned a project

Even for Excel :

[image]

I think is a windows problem, but i try to find a solution on the web and i can't found.

Did you know how to resolve it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Answer from the Microsoft forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/recent-filesprojects-does-not-appear-on-right/65fe7650-3676-46aa-959c-fadfcf34a712?messageId=ba786da3-d45d-4450-9258-88aa3df672ea) :

> Open the Settings App (gear icon on your Start Menu) 
> Go to Personalization - Start 
> Is this setting turned on - Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start and Taskbar?

Comment: I got the same answer, but it doesn't work for me. I turned it off and turned it back on, and pinned files on other applications stayed, but it lost my MRU files on all other applications.

Comment: The other answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/76773514/587767

Answer (score 10):

Testing this issue in 2023 on Windows 11 with Visual Studio Community 2022 I have discovered that it matters HOW you open projects or solutions.  The only way I have found that consistently causes the project or solution to appear in the "recents" list is:

1. Open Visual Studio without a project or solution (the "*Continue without code*" link on the splash screen)
2. Select `File` -> `Open` -> `Project/Solution`
3. Browse to your "*.sln*" or project file, select and open it

After this, the project or solution should finally show in the right-click context menu "recents" section.  From there you can right click the recents item and select to pin it, which I recommend.  Then you don't have to worry about if you opened it in the correct way recently enough.

Comment: That workaround works ok for projects that I work on often. But is there any solution for projects that are worked on infrequently over longer time scales (say, a week), but might be worked on often on a single day? IMO that's really what the 'Recent' list is for, and this bug prevents that from being used.


For example if I have a project that rarely needs updating, or I've created a temporary testbed project, I'm not going to pin it, since I don't want that cluttering up my menu. But I might be switching back to it hundreds of times during the first half of my day.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, in terms of long-lived projects, I pin them to the list. That way they always show up when I right-click.